# setTimeout inside loop run code 1 time then wait and repeat

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

wanting to know if there is a better way to do this or a way to limit the size into a function

```js
let timerOut = false;
if (!timerOut) {
  //do code
  timerOut = true;
  setTimeout(function () {
    timerOut = false;
  }, 6000);
}
```

i need it so if x is true it will do something and wait for set time then if x is still true repeat

this runs in a setInterval

---

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(x);
  tick()
}, 1000);

var x = true;

function tick() {
  if (x) {
    let timerOut = false;
    if (!timerOut) {
      x = false
      timerOut = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        x = true;
        timerOut = false;
      }, 6000);
    }
  }
}
```

x would not be in the setTimeout that is just to make it loop
x would be change by other factors

---

```js
let x = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("hi")
  clearInterval(x)
}, 3000)
```

^answer

Comment: There is no `setInterval` in your code. Can you try to add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: What sets `x` to true? I would use an event instead, and set up a listener for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` which returns the 'id' of the interval.

If you store that id, you can delete that interval whenever you want.

`let x = setInterval(()=>{console.log("hi")}, 3000)`

`clearInterval(x) //deletes that interval`